# Exibir valores somados de uma coluna em html

Tags: php, html, mysql

Possuo a coluna qtd_estoque na tabela cadastraproduto. Em uma div, quero exibir os valores de todas as linhas somados.

Tentei da seguinte maneira, a qual não exibe nenhum valor:

```
<?php
                    $sql2 = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT sum(qtd_estoque) FROM cadastraproduto");
                    $linhas = mysqli_num_rows($sql2);
                    while($linhas = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2)){
                    $linhas['sum(qtd_estoque)'];
                ?>

                <?php
                    }
                ?>
```

Exibindo:

```
    <div class="col-md-3 view-produto-estoque">
                                <p class="p-dashboard"> Estoque </p>
                                <h2 class="p-toal-produtos"><?php echo $linhas; ?></h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde

Você nao precisa fazer o sum na query, tente assim

```
<?php
    $sql2 = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT qtd_estoque FROM cadastraproduto");
    $linhas = mysqli_num_rows($sql2);
?>
```

Mais exemplos na documentação

https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: Acabei de ver que se eu colocar o echo junto do while, o valor é exibido. Acho que meu erro está em puxar esse valor no <h2>